# Is there a website where I can freely download monthly average temperatures per city?

Tags: temperature

I am building a garden calendar app, that uses the average temperature for each month to create a calendar. Are there websites that allow me to easily download this data in json format?

Comment: My first thought that comes to mind is Nasa. I don't think it provides data in a Json format, or even specific data that you are referring to, but it is definitely worth checking out.

Comment: just fyi there is also [OPEN! Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Check out https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/datasets and see if it has what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Out here in the Western U.S. the [Western Regional Climate Center](https://wrcc.dri.edu) offers such historical data for download.  If I recall, their downloads are in .csv format, not .json. However, converting data formats is relatively straightforward for GIS software, such as QGIS.

Comment: thank you. But i'm actually looking for a website that offers global data

Comment: Ok, you might want to edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to get it in JSON format, but you can probably write a simple webscraping script for [Weather Underground](https://www.wunderground.com/). For example, if you want to make a calendar for your best friend in Greenland, you can use https://www.wunderground.com/history/monthly/gl/kangerlussuaq/BGSF. Or, in HTML terms, https://www.wunderground.com/history/monthly/<country>/<city>/<ICAO>/. Of course, I would recommend going to the Weather underground website and exploring a bit to avoid unexpected behavior.